# Fetch Image from sqlite Database flutter

Tags: flutter, image, sqlite

Help me please, I have saved in sqlite image Uint8List as TEXT in database, now i want to display it and i dont know how to fetch with future builder. I have DBHElper with function, but dont know how to get that image and show it with FutureBuilder. Flutter

```
getFromGallery(ImageSource source) async {
    final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();

    XFile? file = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: source);

    if (file != null) {
      return await file.readAsBytes();
    }
  }

  void selectImage() async {
    Uint8List imageFile = await getFromGallery(ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = imageFile;
    });
  }
```

This is the function that saves the image to sqlite

Answer (score 1):

save as TEXT like

```
String imageText = String.fromCharCodes(_image);
```

and convert back to

```
var imageFile = Uint8List.fromList(imageText.codeUnits);
```

Comment: Thanks i will try, look, i have list of recipe save by user in data base and i wanna when press that recipe open up on another screnn descpription to it (image, indegridients, and other things), how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ImageDisplayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int imageId;
  final DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();

  ImageDisplayWidget({required this.imageId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
      future: dbHelper.getImage(imageId),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Image.memory(snapshot.data!);
        } else {
          return Placeholder();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, DBHelper is assumed to have a method called getImage that takes an imageId parameter and returns a Future that retrieves the image data from the database. The ImageDisplayWidget takes an imageId parameter and uses FutureBuilder to asynchronously retrieve and display the image data.

Comment: Thanks i will try, look, i have list of recipe save by user in data base and i wanna when press that recipe open up on another screnn descpription to it (image, indegridients, and other things), how can i do that?